# Daydream App Crashes on starting

Tags: android, crash, android-manifest, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Daydream app for android but it crashes immediately. I dont know what's causing this problem. I think it has something to do with the AndroidManifest but it looks fine to me. I hope someone can help me out because it gets really annoying. P.S. I'm working with Unity 5 so maybe it is'nt possible at all to make a Daydream app with Unity?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.unity3d.player"
     android:installLocation="preferExternal"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0">
     <supports-screens
         android:smallScreens="true"
         android:normalScreens="true"
         android:largeScreens="true"
         android:xlargeScreens="true"
         android:anyDensity="true"/>

    <application
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true">
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
       <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
       </activity>
       <service
             android:name=".MyDream"
             android:exported="true"
             android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DREAM_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             </intent-filter>
             </service>
             </application>
 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be the Manifest.

You are missing important tags from it.

```
<!-- VR feature tags. -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.vr.mode" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vr.high_performance" android:required="false"/>
```

Also

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
```

And to make sure there is no Marshmallow's runtime permission problem, alsi include

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="22"
```

You need to download **[Google VR SDK](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/download)** for Unity to be able to [properly](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started-controller) develop **Daydream App**.

Below is the full Manifest from Google VR SDK.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.google.unity.GoogleUnityActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:launchMode="singleTask"
                  android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="com.google.intent.category.CARDBOARD" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="IMMERSIVE_MODE" android:value="true" />
    </application>
    <!-- Set target sdk version to Lollipop to prevent issues with Marshmallow's runtime permissions. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- VR feature tags. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.vr.mode" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vr.high_performance" android:required="false"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, but i'm not making an app for Google VR. There are 2 things of daydream and that's VR and this:                                              http://www.greenbot.com/article/2151960/how-to-set-up-daydream-android-s-overlooked-customizable-docking-screen.html                                   And i'm making a app for the second daydream

Comment: @DutchDesigner Oops. I didn't know there were 2 things for daydreamer. Cn you explain the second because I am still confused. What does it do and why do need it from Unity?

Comment: Daydream is a screen saver for your Android device while Charging or docked. Settings > Display > Daydream. There are a few standard apps installed And i wanted to make with Unity a custom one. Those standard apps will show a clock or beautyful colors for example. (App = Screensaver for Daydream)